# Advantages of a get<object Name> stored procedure architecture in .NET 4+?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am migrating an existing .NET 2.0, SQL Server codebase to a .NET 4.0, SQL Server 2008 environment.

The design pattern is that all app calls to the database go through a stored procedure. So there's a `get[object name]` stored procedure that needs to be created or altered for most select statements.

So the disadvantages of this architecture to me are already evident: inconvenience.

What are the advantages of this highly enforced stored procedure design? (now in .NET 4.0 as opposed to using an ORM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually - contrary to popular belief - performance isn't one of the advantages of stored procedures - not anymore. Properly written "inline" SQL queries with parameters are just as fast, get "compiled" once by SQL Server (before first use) and remain in the procedure cache of SQL Server just as long as any stored procedure.

But stored procedures do have advantages - two main ones I'd like to mention:

1. the shield the user from the underlying tables. Which also means: it's another layer in your security system. Your database users **do not** need access to the tables - and thus they won't be able to cause any grief on those tables, either - by accessing them via Excel or Access or some other tool. This alone can be a **huge** benefit.
2. the second point is having a layer of stored procedure can give your DBA a place to optimize. You as a developer only call stored procedures - and the DBA can tweak them, fine tune them, make them run faster. As long as the parameter list and the return result set remain the same - you as a frontend developer won't even notice (at least not in a negative way!)

Comment: BUT don't forget that you can accomplish the same using views, provided your DBMS supports them.

Comment: @Paul: for selecting data - yes - but for inserting/updating/deleting, not so much ... (usually)

Comment: True, but I was thinking in terms of the scenario described in the original question...

Comment: But once you've read the data - chances are, you'll want to update it, too :-)

Comment: Sure it is, except for maybe some highly specialized ID lookups, plus if your DBMS supports 'cached' or 'indexed' views, you can perform optimizations not possible using SPs.

Comment: @Paul: true again on the indexed views - but mind you: those **also** take up space on disk - typically much more than a stored procedure :-) And yes - I know - disk space is cheap - but you still have to have it first - and it's cheap - not free...

Comment: Yes parameterized statements perform much the same as stored procedures.  The biggest difference is the code maintainability.  With procedures you can change the underlying functionality of something without recompiling code.  With parameterized statements any changes to the tables or functionality of the sql requires a recompile of code.  Performance is not adversely affected between the two.  ORM creates parameterized sql anyway under the covers.  Again with ORM if there is a change to the tables it would require a code recompile as attributes are mapped to columns in the DB

Comment: @denas also there is some functionality that ORMs simply don't support (or require you to jump through hoops to get it).

Comment: @denas changes to schema do not necessarily require a recompile of code when using an ORM, what makes you think that?

Comment: it doesn't "necessarily" mean it would require a recompile but I've found those that have not implemented it before use strict mappings which would require it... depends on how you have it implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I take the approach of stored procs for INSERT/ UPDATE / DELETE for objects and do SELECTs in application code. Advantages:

- Clear separation of business logic and data
- Data security is better because it is controlled at the database layer.
- Doing SELECTs in business logic is a compromise that anyone can read table data if they get the database login credentials, but they cant modify it (assuming you setup object level permissions correctly (tables read-only)), but i don't have to write a stored proc for every variant of where criteria.
- its easier to customize data operations when you write your own data adapters vs ORMs
- ORMs are fine, but there's typically alot of overhead in ORMs and i like the approach of my applications creating the least amount of work possible for the machines they run on. Plus I know exactly what is happening and there's less 'magic' happening behind the scenes

Disadvantages:

- You can generate alot of code if you don't use ORMs, which means more to maintain.
- It's fair to say that writing your own data adapters is re-inventing the wheel. more control always comes with a cost

Answer (score -3):

Stored procedures greatest benefit is - execution time. If you have "heavy" SQL queries you should use SP.

Comment: Actually - no. A well written "ad-hoc" query - properly done with parameters - is just as fast, just as performant as any stored procedure. That's definitely **not** (any more) a big plus for stored procedures, sorry.

Comment: Since SQL Server can optimize at the statement level, I don't think performance is the greatest benefit anymore. Not having to change, recompile and redeploy application code is much greater IMHO. Never mind centralizing code in cases where multiple applications might need the same data, and preventing things like ORMs from destroying performance by doing very dumb things to give the app what it wants.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'd love to send you a Swiss chocolate bar - unfortunately, your Dept of Homeland Security will confiscate it - biohazard / potential bio-terrorism .... (sad, but true ....)